# Angular2 change variable of different class

Tags: angular

I have 3 classes in my ng2 Application. The first class manages, which directive is being used by an `*ngIf`, which by default includes the second class. And in the template of the second class I want to change the directive name from the first class, which would then trigger the first class to recheck the if statement and than select the third class.

Or generally said, is it bad practise to check with `*ngIf` for the directive to use?

**Edit:**

as stated by Günter Zöchbauer, here is some Code for what i try to do:

**/app/app.component.ts:**

```
template: `
    <div *ngIf="template == 'menu'">
        <menu></menu>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="template == 'entry'">
        <entries></entries>
    </div>
`
[...]
export class AppComponent {
    public template = "menu";

    public setTemplate(newTemplate: string) {
        this.template = newTemplate;
    }
}
```

**/app/menu/menu.component.html:**

```
[...]
(click)="setTemplate('entry')"
[...]
```

Now I am looking for something to call `setTemplate('entry')` from the app.component.ts instead of menu.component.ts

Comment: Can you please add some code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish (components with templates)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use an [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/EventEmitter-class.html) inside the menu component, so your source could look like this:

*/app/menu/menu.component.html:*

```
[...]
<div (click)="fireMyEvent('categories')">Categories</div>
<div (click)="fireMyEvent('entries')">Entries</div>
[...]

@Output() myEvent: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
fireMyEvent(evtParam: string) {
    this.myEvent.emit(evtParam);
}
```

*/app/app.component.ts:*

```
template: `
    <menu (myEvent)="setTemplate($event)"></menu>
    <div *ngIf="template == 'categories'">
        <categories></categories>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="template == 'entries'">
        <entries></entries>
    </div>
`
[...]
```

Or what about handling the click event of the menu component itself from the outside?

*/app/app.component.ts:*

```
    <div *ngIf="template == 'menu'">
        <menu (click)="setTemplate('menu')"></menu>
    </div>
```

Comment: it should be `this.myEvent.emit(null)`. Right?

Comment: Yeah, thank you very much, that's precisely what I needed to do!

Comment: But what, if I would need to pass the new template to fireMyEvent() so that it's not hardcoded setTemplate('menu')

Comment: @IvanSieder I don't really understand you. `myEvent` does know nothing about `setTemplate`, so the parameter simply can't be hardcoded. This solution is to implement loose coupling between `AppComponent` and `MenuComponent`.

Comment: well the idea was to always pass the template to select the requered template through fireMyEvent() and then in the fireMyEvent somehow pass the variable, so that the (myEvent) in the template has somehow access to that passed variable

Comment: You could implement something like `<menu valueToEcho="main" (myEvent)="setTarget($event.echoedValue) />"` or `<menu (myEvent)="setTarget($event.sourceComponentName) />"` But that would be nothing better than the current one. That would require to change the child components to fit better to AppComponent, thus depending on it indirectly. I think that should be avoided.

Comment: But the problem i have is, that the template is being maybe changed to entry, and entry has again that handler. And it can happen, that inside <menu></menu>, on a click, different templates could be loaded (so it's not just "entries", but it could also be "components" etc. Therefor i would need to get the passed value from the menu component

Comment: You can supply a value to the event by `myEvent.emit("something")`

Comment: And a last question: how can i access the value passed through myEvent.emit("something")? Don't get it from the docu

Comment: ah okay, got it. just by passing $event

Comment: Yes, I should've mentioned `$event`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a template variable `#menu`.

If the tag where you add it is a native element, it hold a reference to the DOM element. If it is an Angular component you get a reference to the component.
In expressions you can reference it like

```
<menu #menu (click)="menu.setTemplate($event)"></menu>
```

Comment: well, but how does that will work? I have the *ngIf in the /app/app.component.ts and the menu and menu template is in app/menu/. So where should i exactly add that?

Comment: I can't see from your question or from the comments where you **want** to call it from. If the element is removed because the expressin in `ngIf` is false then there is nothing to call from or to because it doesn't exist.

Comment: The solution from Tamas Hegedus seems to work fine for what I need, thanks anyway for your effort!